# change the image using label.text value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one `lable` called `post.label.text = 5` . And I have 30 image view which size is 8 X 8. by default i have small dot image. When the value of my `post.label.text` is 5 , i need to change some of the 5 image out of 30 image should change to big dots image

i.e:

```
total image small dots = 30 image dots

   should change from small to big dots = 5 image dots
```

I know to use if condition , but i have 30 images and for example if my `post.label.text = 1` means i need to show only one small dot images to big dot image.

Please help me. i am new to ios.Thanks in advance!

My image declaation is like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage *dot1;

       up to

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage *dot30;
```

And i did `@synch of all dots 1 to 30` in .m file. after that what should i do to change the dots image based on the `label.text` value

I have more images so using if i cant change each image to chnage from small to big dots. IS there any idea to do. Please explain with some code.

I did in this way:

```
 if (sLabel.text > 10) {

     // imgV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"small dot.png"];

    }
```

but how i will do for all value for >1 , >2, so on. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: See screen shot]Create connection outlet of all image properties;

```
@property IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *imgArray;
```

Next -

```
self.post.text = @"5";
int postValue = [self.post.text intValue];
for (int i=29; i>(29-postValue); i--)
{ 
    UIImageView *currImageView = [self.imgArray objectAtIndex:i];
      currImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"big dot.png"]; 
}
```

Comment: my oulet name for all image is `imgV` to `imgv30`. But i am new to ios. how to create a common array that should hold all image name

Comment: i tried this`NSArray *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparente.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"21001.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"21002.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"21003.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"21004.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparente2.png"],
                        nil];`

Comment: i saw this code in SO. but they used their image name. but i have outlet name

Comment: You would have drag and created UIImageView outlets from storyboard or NIB file.

Comment: i used storyboard to drag and drop all 30 images. And i add each uiimage name as `imgV` TO `imgV30`

Comment: You would have drag and created UIImageView outlets from storyboard or NIB file. After that, write this collection property in .h file. And drag all image views from story board to this collection. I have edited my response with attached screenshot. Please check that again.

Comment: see my main answer again. that would help you I hope.

Comment: Yes i too saw this code. But i need to change my small dot do big dot in anticlock wise. if i do in this way my small image are changed to big image in clockwise only know. so only i kept seperate imagView for all

Comment: in your code it is posssible to do that small dot to big dot image in anticlockwise

Comment: Okay. its simple, in that case make the loop reverse. for (int i=30; i>(30-postValue); i--) {
    UIImageView *currImageView = [self.imgArray objectAtIndex:i];
    currImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"big dot.png"];
}   This will change them in anti-clockwise direction.

Comment: its not readable . i too new to ios. can you update your answer with your code please

Comment: will check and tell you vikas

Comment: should i select all uiimage in from count 1 to 30 . that means should i select all image one by one next from first

Comment: its getting crash when i pass `label.text` value from 1 to 30. error:   `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 30 beyond bounds [0 .. 29]'`

Comment: but when i pass value 0, its not getting crash

Comment: Joseph, you need to give two outlet connection here. One separate connection for all UIImageView to their respective outlet; and next, add all UIImageView to the collection outlet (commonly).

Comment: Sorry, your loop should start from 29, not 30; as total array size is 30 so indexes will be from 0 to 29;

Comment: Updated the answer. Just change this line - for (int i=29; i>(29-postValue); i--)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this Joseph

 self.post.text =@"5";
int value = [self.post.text intValue];
for (int i=0; i<value; i++) {
    UIImage *images =[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dot%d",i]];
    imgV.image = images;
}
```

Comment: Thnaks for your solution. But i have one doubt. That `imgV` is only one image name. like wise i am having 30 `imgv30`. How can i add that with `images`

Comment: my 30 images name are` imgv to imgV30`

Comment: Let you add all your image view to one array.. self.post.text =@"5";
    int value = [self.post.text intValue];
    for (int i=0; i<value; i++) {
        UIImage *images =[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dot%d",i]];
        UIImageView *imgview  = [self.imageviewarray objectAtIndex:i];
        imgview.image = images;
    }

Comment: And that `stringwithFormat :@"dot%d", i`  =  in this line `dot ` is big dot image or what??

Comment: does that `dot ` is you mention the big dot image?? by default i have small dot image . i need to change that small dot to big dot based on `label.text` value

Comment: This is the image which you want to display. Suppose you want to show 2 images as your label value is 2. Then it will show image1 and image2

Comment: i tried this `NSArray *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparente.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"21001.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"21002.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"21003.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"21004.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparente2.png"], nil];`

Comment: i saw this code in SO. but they used their image name. but i have outlet name

Comment: @property(nonatomic,retain)UIImageView *imgV1;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)UIImageView *imgV2;
    NSArray *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: imgV1,imgV2, nil];